# Onclick to do show/hide activates submit button in form

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, submit

I have a form for booking people on a day trip that has been working fine. Each booking is a row in a table. I now require to add the payment for the trip to each booking.  That would make the row for each booking too long, so I added the payments as an extra row below each booking, but hid the row with a button in the parent row to show and hide the payments.  That all works, except that everytime I click on the show/hide button in the parent row, the form submits as though I had clicked the save submit button at the bottom of the form.  Since the save reports results in a new tab, I can go back to the original form and see that the show/hide has worked fine.

Any ideas as to why the show/hide button should initiate the action statement in the original form tag would be appreciated.  The total script is substantial, so I've just shown the form tag and the extra code I have added for the show/hide. $i is number of the row in the table. $background is setting the background colour of the row.

I have show/hides in other forms without any problems, but this is the first time I have used it within a table. I've already used a couple of posts in this forum to get the show/hide to work properly for a table row, but haven't found anything so far to address this issue.

```
    <form method="post" action="visit_management.php?mode=book" target="_blank">
      ...
      <td><button id="button_'.$i.'" onclick="showpayment_'.$i.'()">Show payments</button></td>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
        function showpayment_'.$i.'() 
        {
          var x = document.getElementById("payment_'.$i.'");
          var y = document.getElementById("button_'.$i.'");
          if (x.style.display === "none") 
          {
            x.style.display = "table-row";
            y.innerHTML = "Hide payments";
          } 
          else 
          {
            x.style.display = "none";
            y.innerHTML = "Show payments";
          }
        }
      -->       
      </script>
      ...
      <tr id="payment_'.$i.'" style="display:none; '.$background.'">
      ...  Payment data
      </tr>
      ...
      <p><input type="submit" style="padding-top:5px" value="Save" class="formsubmit"></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of a `<button>` within a `<form>` is to submit the form.

So you can change your `<button>` to `<div class="button">` and add some css to `.button`

Or you can pass the event to the function `onclick="showpayment_'.$i.'(event)`, and then call preventDefault(); like:

```
  function showpayment_'.$i.'(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var x = document.getElementById("payment_'.$i.'");
    var y = document.getElementById("button_'.$i.'");
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realise that it was "linked" to a form.  I can now deal with the problem.  I already have class of button that I use elsewhere, just thought I'd use ``<button>`` this time as it seemed neater in use and I was still unhappy about the presentation of my button class. Obviously ``<button>`` has its restrictions.

Comment: I've just remembered that I thought I had read somewhere that you shouldn't use ``<div>`` within a table, although I have just done it as quick experiment and it seem to work.